# Create a matrix so that when printed it appears as a "*" frame. R poject

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix that when is printed only appears the "frame" of the matrix. Below the simple code to create a square matrix

```
matrix_maker <- function() {

 x <- as.integer(readline("Number of rows and columns: "))

 matrix(data = '*',
     nrow = x,
     ncol = x)
 }
```

The printed result has to be something like this:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
   [1,] *     *    *    *
   [2,] *               * 
   [3,] *               * 
   [4,] *     *    *    *
```

Thanks

Comment: You always want a square matrix? (e.g. a single input)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the interior of your matrix to ""

```
matrix_maker <- function() {
  x <- as.integer(readline("Number of rows and columns: "))
  y <- matrix(data = '*', nrow = x, ncol = x)
  if(x > 2){
    y[2:(nrow(y)-1), 2:(ncol(y)-1)] <- ""
  }
  return(y)
}
```

As @David Arenburg pointed out, another option would be to set the whole matrix to "" and then the frame to "*".

```
matrix_maker <- function() {
  x <- as.integer(readline("Number of rows and columns: "))
  y <- matrix(data = '', nrow = x, ncol = x)
  y[row(y) %in% c(1,x) | col(y) %in% c(1,x)] <- "*"
  y
}
```

Comment: You are right, I forgot to return y, when putting it into a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix_maker <- function() {
 y<-noquote("*")
  x <- as.integer(readline("Number of rows and columns: "))
  m<-matrix(data = y,
         nrow = x,
         ncol = x)
  if(ncol(m)%in%c(0,1,2)) return(m)
 ifelse(ncol(m)%%2!=0,m[2:(nrow(m)-1),2:(nrow(m)-1)]<-" ",
        m[2:(nrow(m)-1),2:(ncol(m)-1)]<-" ")

  m
}
```

Call it like so:

```
 noquote(matrix_maker())

   Number of rows and columns: 5
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] *    *    *    *    *   
[2,] *                   *   
[3,] *                   *   
[4,] *                   *   
[5,] *    *    *    *    *
```

Try something else:

```
noquote(matrix_maker())
Number of rows and columns: 4
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] *    *    *    *   
[2,] *              *   
[3,] *              *   
[4,] *    *    *    *
```

Comment: Now try something differnt as input for the readline as for example 2 or 5.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought OP needs strictly a four by four.

Comment: Ok, now call it with 1 :D

Comment: You should also try it with 0. Then a <0 x 0> matrix will be created.